# gulp-jscs save report to file

Tags: gulp, jscs, gulp-jscs

Is there a possibility to run `jscs` check and using gulp and save report it produces to a file?
I want `junit` style xml files reports saved somewhere. I can do this using direct command line call with `>` but how to do it using proper gulp?

Comment: Not sure if there is such a plugin already, but might not be hard to write it yourself. See e.g. [`gulp-jscs-stylish` source](https://github.com/gonsfx/gulp-jscs-stylish/blob/master/index.js) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-log-capture`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-log-capture) to capture the output of `gulp-jscs` and write it to a file.

```
var logCapture = require('gulp-log-capture');

gulp.task('checkstyle', () => {
  return gulp.src('*.js')
    .pipe(jscs({fix:true}))
    .pipe(logCapture.start(console, 'log'))
    .pipe(jscs.reporter('junit'))
    .pipe(logCapture.stop('xml'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('junit-reports'));
});
```

Note that this will produce one JUnit-style XML output file per JS input file.